# Arbitrary number of operations in lambda function in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I have a simple lambda function to calculate the total of integer multiples in a certain range.  Right now it is totaling multiples of 3 and 5.

```
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 999)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream().filter(n -> n%3 == 0 || n%5 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I would like to take an arbitrary list of numbers and write a lambda function that checks a range for multiples of all those numbers.  i.e. if I pass in 3 & 5 I want multiples of those, if i pass 6, 9, 11 i want multiples of those three.  I imagine it looks something like this:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 999)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream().filter(n -> for(int mult : multiples)if(n%mult==0)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Is this possible or do lambdas require a fixed number of operations?

Comment: What is the type of `multiples`?

Comment: multiples is declared as a List<Integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream your multiples as well and use `anyMatch`.
Also note that you don't need to `collect` in between, you usually only want to `collect` when all your work is done on the `Stream`. The boxing can be done right before collecting, until then you can work with the `IntStream`.

```
int[] multiples = { 3, 5, 7 };
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 999)
    .filter(n -> IntStream.of(multiples).anyMatch(k -> n % k == 0))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: You should mention that/why you eliminated the intermediate `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()`. While you do that, you should also move the `.boxed()` down after the `.filter()`. No need to box until you're ready to build a `List`. For general viewing, it's easier to see the stream chain if you write each on a new line, aligning on the `.`.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, updated my answer according to your comment

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help!